# When trying to render a cube, all the triangles get rendered into a line

Tags: c++, 3d, sdl-2

I have been doing [javidx9's 3D Graphics series](https://youtu.be/ih20l3pJoeU) except with SDL2 instead of the olcConsleGameEngine and I have gotten to the part before rotation. and all the triangles when rendered just turn into a line in the middle-ish of the screen

Code

3D.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "SDL.h"

struct Vector3
{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct Triangle
{
    Vector3 points[3];
};

struct Mesh
{
    std::vector<Triangle> Triangles;
};

struct Matrix4x4
{
    float m[4][4] = {0};
};

class Camera
{
public:
    Mesh cube;
    Matrix4x4 projectionMatrix;
    void init(int width, int height, float FOV, float nearPlane, float farPlane) {
        cube.Triangles = {
            { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
            { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },
            { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
            { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
            { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
            { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
            { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
            { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },
            { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
            { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
            { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },
            { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },
        };
        float fovRad = 1.0f / tanf(FOV * 0.5f / 180.0f * 3.14159f);
        projectionMatrix.m[0][0] = (float)(height/width)*fovRad;
        projectionMatrix.m[1][1] = fovRad;
        projectionMatrix.m[2][2] = farPlane / (farPlane - nearPlane);
        projectionMatrix.m[3][2] = (-farPlane * nearPlane) / (farPlane - nearPlane);
        projectionMatrix.m[2][3] = 1.0f;
        projectionMatrix.m[3][3] = 0.0f;
    }
    //vector<Triangle2D> render(int width, int height) {
    void renderTriangle(int width, int height, SDL_Renderer* renderer, Triangle tri) {
            Triangle triProjected, triTranslated;
            triTranslated = tri;
            triTranslated.points[0].z = tri.points[0].z + 3.0f;
            triTranslated.points[1].z = tri.points[1].z + 3.0f;
            triTranslated.points[2].z = tri.points[2].z + 3.0f;
            MultiplyMatrixVector(triTranslated.points[0], triProjected.points[0], projectionMatrix);
            MultiplyMatrixVector(triTranslated.points[1], triProjected.points[1], projectionMatrix);
            MultiplyMatrixVector(triTranslated.points[2], triProjected.points[2], projectionMatrix);
            triProjected.points[0].x += 1.0f;
            triProjected.points[0].y += 1.0f;
            triProjected.points[1].x += 1.0f;
            triProjected.points[1].y += 1.0f;
            triProjected.points[2].x += 1.0f;
            triProjected.points[2].y += 1.0f;
            triProjected.points[0].x *= 0.5f * (float)width;
            triProjected.points[0].y *= 0.5f * (float)height;
            triProjected.points[1].x *= 0.5f * (float)width;
            triProjected.points[1].y *= 0.5f * (float)height;
            triProjected.points[2].x *= 0.5f * (float)width;
            triProjected.points[2].y *= 0.5f * (float)height;
            SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, (int)triProjected.points[0].x, (int)triProjected.points[0].y, (int)triProjected.points[1].x, (int)triProjected.points[1].y);
            SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, (int)triProjected.points[1].x, (int)triProjected.points[1].y, (int)triProjected.points[2].x, (int)triProjected.points[2].y);
            SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, (int)triProjected.points[2].x, (int)triProjected.points[2].y, (int)triProjected.points[0].x, (int)triProjected.points[0].y);
            //exit(1);
    }
    void MultiplyMatrixVector(Vector3 &i, Vector3 &o, Matrix4x4 &m) {
        o.x = i.x * m.m[0][0] + i.y * m.m[1][0] + i.z * m.m[2][0] + m.m[3][0];
        o.y = i.x * m.m[0][1] + i.y * m.m[1][1] + i.z * m.m[2][1] + m.m[3][1];
        o.z = i.x * m.m[0][2] + i.y * m.m[1][2] + i.z * m.m[2][2] + m.m[3][2];
        float w = i.x * m.m[0][3] + i.y * m.m[1][3] + i.z * m.m[2][3] + m.m[3][3];

        if (w != 0.0f)
        {
            o.x /= w; o.y /= w; o.z /= w;
        }
    }
};
```

Game.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "SDL.h"
#include "3D.h"

void draw2DTriangle(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int ax, int ay, int bx, int by, int cx, int cy)
{
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, ax, ay, bx, by);
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, bx, by, cx, cy);
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, cx, cy, ax, ay);
}

class Game {
public:
    Game() {};
    ~Game() {};


    void init(const char* title, int width, int height, bool fullscreen) {
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
        int flags = SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN;
        if (fullscreen) {
            int flags = SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
        }
        window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, flags);
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        isRunning = true;
        camera.init(1280, 720, 90.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    };


    void update() {

    };


    void render() {
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        camera.renderTriangle(1280, 720, renderer, camera.cube.Triangles[0]);
        camera.renderTriangle(1280, 720, renderer, camera.cube.Triangles[1]);
        camera.renderTriangle(1280, 720, renderer, camera.cube.Triangles[2]);
        camera.renderTriangle(1280, 720, renderer, camera.cube.Triangles[3]);
        camera.renderTriangle(1280, 720, renderer, camera.cube.Triangles[4]);
        camera.renderTriangle(1280, 720, renderer, camera.cube.Triangles[5]);
        camera.renderTriangle(1280, 720, renderer, camera.cube.Triangles[6]);
        camera.renderTriangle(1280, 720, renderer, camera.cube.Triangles[7]);
        camera.renderTriangle(1280, 720, renderer, camera.cube.Triangles[8]);
        camera.renderTriangle(1280, 720, renderer, camera.cube.Triangles[9]);
        camera.renderTriangle(1280, 720, renderer, camera.cube.Triangles[10]);
        camera.renderTriangle(1280, 720, renderer, camera.cube.Triangles[11]);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    };


    void handleEvents() {
        SDL_Event event;
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
        switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            isRunning = false;
            break;
        }
    };


    void clean() {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_Quit();
    };


    bool running() { return isRunning; };

private:
    bool isRunning{};
    SDL_Window* window{};
    SDL_Renderer* renderer{};
    Camera camera;
};
```

I have debugged a bit and eliminated the MultiplyMatrixVector, so I think its not that at the least

Comment: It's a bit difficult to follow your code (reduce the number of vertices & triangles, remove unused funcs, etc). At the first sight, I don't trust your perspective projection matrix.

Comment: Your code is a mess. Why is a `cube` inside the `Camera`? Why does the `Camera` render things? If anything, it should just be a glorified wrapper around a projection matrix. Why is `draw2DTriangle` here? It's not used anywhere. Why does `Game` have `init` and `clean` functions instead of making use of its constructor and destructor?

Comment: @Nelfeal That's like that because I am going to change it later,
First I just wanted to get a cube to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Camera::init`, you have this line:

```
projectionMatrix.m[0][0] = (float)(height/width)*fovRad;
```

Unfortunately, `(float)(height/width)` does not do what you want. It does an integer division first and then casts the result to `float`. Just replace the line with either one of these:

```
// C++ style cast
projectionMatrix.m[0][0] = static_cast<float>(height) / width * fovRad;
// Implicit cast
projectionMatrix.m[0][0] = fovRad * height / width;
// C style cast (no need to parenthesize the expression)
projectionMatrix.m[0][0] = (float)height / width * fovRad;
```

Alternatively, since you don't need `height` and `width` for anything other than their ratio, you could just take that ratio as a parameter:

```
void init(float aspectRatio, float FOV, float nearPlane, float farPlane) {
    // ...
    projectionMatrix.m[0][0] = aspectRatio * fovRad;
    // ...
}
// ...
float aspectRatio = static_cast<float>(height) / width;
camera.init(aspectRatio, 90.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
```